# Bad position equation number Lualatex

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, luatex

If a math display is too wide, then the `\eqno` appears on the next line on the left instead of on the right as it should. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? This is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}     
\newcommand{\si}[1]{\ensuremath{\sigma_{#1}^{2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   C=   
\begin{bmatrix}
    {C_{11} } & {C_{12} }  \\
    {C_{21} } & {C_{22} }  \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \E\left[ {\left( {X-m_{X}} \right)^{2}} \right] & \E\left[ {\left( {X-m_{X}} \right)\left( {Y-m_{Y}} \right)} \right] \\
    \E\left[ {\left( {X-m_{X}} \right)\left( {Y-m_{Y}} \right)} \right] & \E\left[ {\left( {Y-m_{Y}} \right)^{2}} \right] 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \si{X} & C_{XY} \\
    C_{XY} & \si{Y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

*Added by Hendrik Vogt:*

The same happens with plain LuaTeX.

```
\hsize=2cm
$$a^2+b^2=c^2\eqno(1)$$
\bye
```

Ouput after compilation with `luatex`:

[image: eqno in the left]

Ouput after compilation with `pdftex`:

[image: eqno in the right]

Dear friends: I think the next code is a posible, and provisional solution:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{equationw}
{
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\BODY
\end{split}\end{equation}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I took the freedom to add another MWE with sample outputs. (To me it seems like a bug in the LuaTeX engine.)

Comment: it is correct with `xelatex`. However you should use package `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}` and not loading `mathptmx` when running `lualatex`

Comment: Just to let you know, if my answer helped you, then you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark at the top left `:-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the LuaTeX engine, see below. For a workaround, use `align` instead of `equation`; the `align` environment doesn't rely on the TeX engine for placement of the equation number. This fixes your problem (but can influence the *vertical* spacing for *shorter* equations).

---

I *think* I could locate the bug in [`texmath.w`](http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/ctan/systems/luatex/base/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/texmath.w), lines 2220 to 2225. There it says

```
if ((eqno_box != null) && (eqno_w == 0) && !l) {
    tail_append(new_penalty(inf_penalty));
    shift_amount(eqno_box) = line_s;
    append_to_vlist(eqno_box);
    g2 = 0;
}
```

Of interest is the third line: the shift amount of the box containing the equation number is `line_s`, which previously was set to `\displayindent` (which usually is zero). Thus, the equation number is flush left.

Here's the corresponding lines from Knuth's [`tex.web`](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web), lines 22580 to 22585:

```
if (a<>null)and(e=0)and not l then
  begin tail_append(new_penalty(inf_penalty));
  shift_amount(a):=s+z-width(a);
  append_to_vlist(a);
  g2:=0;
  end;
```

You can see that this is the very same code in a different language, `eqno_box != null` translates to `a<>null`, and so on. Here, the shift amount of the box containing the equation number is `s+z-width(a)`, where `s` is the same as `line_s` above, `z` is the line width and `width(a)`, well, the width of the box `a` with the equation number. And this is the correct shift amount for having the equation number flush right!

Maybe I should explain the conditions in the first line of the code: the box with the equation number should be non-empty, it should have width 0(!), and we shouldn't be in the case of a **l**eft equation number as in `\leqno`. And why the width 0? This is the "flag" that was set before to indicate that the box should be placed in the next line because it didn't fit into the line with the equation.

Comment: Could you please open a bug at [the LuaTeX bug tracker](http://tracker.luatex.org/main_page.php)?

Comment: @Martin: Hmm, I had a look and didn't find where I can report this. Would I have to sign up?

Comment: http://tracker.luatex.org/bug_report_page.php - and yes, you need an account.

Comment: @Martin: I don't really want yet another account somewhere. I don't even use LuaTeX ... May I ask you to do the report for me? Maybe it suffices to point to my answer here.

Comment: Agreed, it is a (previously unknown) engine bug.
Submitted as http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=807

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I like the idea, but can you please email me or the luatex mailing list? SX is not the best place to discuss these things.